# Python common variable verification within function

Tags: python

To make the function regarding time series in Python more dynamic with inputs, I always write the code as follows to verify if I have input variable(s):

```
def function_a(start_date=None, end_date=None):

if start_date == None:
    start_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(10), '%Y-%m-%d')
else:
    start_date = start_date

if end_date == None:
    end_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d')
else:
    end_date = end_date
```

If there is no input from users, the default dates will be used.

However, I was wondering what is your common practice to perform such verification activity, could you suggest some? Thanks in advance!

Comment: fwiw..  you would normally write ```if start_date is None:```

Comment: Exactly, identities should be compared with the `is` keyword, values with the `==` operator

Answer (score 0):

You may have different interesting options for this case:

```
start_date_value = start_date or datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(10), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Another option would be:

```
start_date_value = start_date if start_date is not None else datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(10), '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go for a one liner if :

```
var = default_value if var is None else other_value
```

```
def function_a(start_date=None, end_date=None):
    start_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(10), '%Y-%m-%d') if start_date is None
    end_date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%Y-%m-%d') if end_date is None
```